# Displaying An Array big elements

Tags: c++

I want to display array using a method, if the array has under 200 elements it display all the elements, which works fine for me. The problem is if the array has over 200 elements i want to display the first 100 elements and the last 100 elements of an array. It works if I use an array of 500 elements or even 10000, but I type something like 9999 or 8999 I get long negative integer numbers on the bottom half of my display list but the top half half works. Any advice?

```
int main()
{
   string fileName,text, size;
   fstream inText;
   int lengthOf = 0;
   cout << "Please Enter An Input File Name: ";
   getline(cin, fileName);
   inText.open(fileName.c_str() , fstream::in);
   if(!inText)
   {
       cout << "Could Not Open " << fileName << " File" << endl;
       exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }
   else
   {
   inText >> lengthOf;
   int * myArray  = new int[lengthOf];
   for(int i = 0; i < lengthOf; i++)
   {
        inText >> myArray[i];
   }

   cout << "Data File Array " << endl;
   displayArray(myArray,lengthOf);

 }
 return 0;
 }
void displayArray (int a[], int s)
{
if(s <= 200)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < s; ++i)
    {
        if(i%10 == 0)
        {
            cout << endl;
        }
        cout << setw(6) << a[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
else
{
    for(int  i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        if(i%10 == 0)
        {
            cout << endl;
        }
        cout << setw(6) << a[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
    for (int i = s-100; i < s; ++i)
    {
        if (i%10 == 0)
        {
            cout << endl;
        }
        cout  << setw(6) << a[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
   }

}
```

Comment: Does the *entire* array print correctly (i.e. if you skip your first/last logic and just comment out the `if` test and return after the dump)? As there is no error checking whatsoever in that  input loop, It's hard to say if you actually populated the entire thing or not.

Comment: Well when I check it with 500 elements or 1000 elements I go through my text file and look the result,  the first 100 elements match and the last 100 match so it must mean something right? Maybe your right, I still don't quite understand what you mean

Comment: What I'm saying is, perhaps validate that the *entire* content of your array is, in fact, actually populated from the file rather than assuming that input loop, void of any validation, actually worked. Gotta start with the basics.

Comment: [Something like this](http://pastebin.com/GxfPWFFP) (warning, untested, but you get the idea).

Comment: Are you sure that every value in the 8999-element array can fit in an `int`?

Comment: Also, just a nitpick, but in the `i = s-100` loop, you should probably check for `i%10 == (s-100)%10` instead of `i%10 == 0`.  It'll throw your formatting off, otherwise.

Comment: Try using [this program](http://ideone.com/oJBGwA) to generate test data, and see if it still happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Printing the array is straight forward, example:

```
int main()
{
    int a[551]; //some random number
    int s = 551;
    for (int i = 0; i < s; ++i) a[i] = i;

    for (int i = 0; i < s; ++i)
    {
        if (i % 10 == 0) cout << "\n";
        if (i % 100 == 0) cout << "\n";
        cout << std::setw(6) << a[i] << " ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When reading the file you can use `std::vector` to store the integers, this way you don't have to know how big the array should be before hand. The example below reads text and then tries to convert to integer, this way you know if there was an error in input file.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    std::string fileName;
    cout << "Please Enter An Input File Name: ";
    getline(cin, fileName);
    std::ifstream inText(fileName);
    std::vector<int> vec;
    std::string temp;
    while (inText >> temp)
    {
        try {
            int i = std::stoi(temp);
            vec.push_back(i);
        }
        catch (...) {
            cout << temp << " - error reading integer\n";
        }
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < vec.size(); ++i)
    {
        if (i % 10 == 0) cout << "\n";
        if (i % 100 == 0) cout << "\n";
        cout << std::setw(6) << vec[i] << " ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are You sure the problem is with this method? The code seems to work, I can't reproduce Your problem. Maybe You could paste Your whole code (if its not too big)?

Comment: Yeah sure, ill do it.